# Problem loading resources in multiple builds

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm a beginner learning scala/sbt. For multiple build projects, like this example:

```
|-- Bar
|   |-- build.sbt
|   +-- src
|       |-- main
|       |   |-- java
|       |   |-- resources
|       |   |    +-- config
|       |   |         +-- app.properties
|       |   +-- scala
|       |       +-- Bar.scala
|       +-- test
|           |-- java
|           +-- resources
|-- Foo
|   |-- build.sbt
|   +-- src
|       |-- main
|       |   |-- java
|       |   |-- resources
|       |   +-- scala
|       |       +-- Foo.scala
|       +-- test
|           |-- java
|           +-- resources
|-- build.sbt
|-- project
|   |-- Build.scala
```

In `Bar.scala`, I tried to load files from resources but its not finding it:

```
val resourcesPath = getClass.getResource("config/app.properties")
println(resourcesPath.getPath)

>> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: How are you running the application?

Comment: I'm running in intellij, right click + run Bar.scala

Comment: What happens if you use sbt directly, e.g. `sbt Bar/run`?

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution @DougKruger ?